# How to create internal links from table-row to table in XSL?

Tags: xsl-fo

Using xsl-fo, I have a table presenting a summary of my data. Each table-row in this summary table corresponds to a table containing all the information of the given row

I would like to create internal links between the summary table-rows and the corresponding detailed tables. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. For each of the detailed tables, generate an `id` property with a unique value.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#id
2. In the summary table, generate an `fo:basic-link` around the text in each table cell that you want to turn into a link to a detailed table.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_basic-link
3. For each `fo:basic-link`, generate an `internal-destination` that has the same value as the `id` property of the detailed table that the link will refer to.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#internal-destination

Note that you don't need to start the `internal-destination` property value with `#`.

For an example of `fo:basic-link` in action, see 'External / Internal Links in PDF (basic-link)' in the Antenna House 'Comprehensive XSL-FO Tutorials and Samples Collection' page at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/.  Note that some of the `internal-destination` values in the example -- such as linking to a page or setting the zoom -- are Antenna House extensions (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.destination-type-internal-pagenumber-link).